# Plotting number of texts through time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot the frequency through time of a dataset.

```
Date              Col1                 Col2            Label
0   2020-05-28  It is not true that ... www.love.com    COOL
1   2020-05-28  Japan, tourism ...  www.travel.com      COOL
2   2020-05-31  You are the best     loving                 1
3   2020-05-31  Incredible!!! You won  who                  0
4   2020-05-28  Mickey Mouse rules the world!  myphone.com  1
```

I would like to plot the number of texts by date. I did as follows

```
df_plot = df.groupby(["Date"]).count().reset_index()
df_plot
```

Then I used seaborn to plot the frequency as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns

df_plot['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df_plot.Date)
sns.scatterplot(x = 'Date', y = 'Col2', hue='Label', data = df_plot)
```

but the output is not as I would expect (x axis does not show months so I have one column and no possibility to spot the trend).

Can you please have a look at these steps and tell me if I am doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: How do you have columns in a scatter plot - can you upload an image of what your plot looks like

Comment: Hi Chris. I just updated the question with the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

From the OP's image, it looks like there may be some spurious or earlier dates in the `df`. When I try with the example data provided, it works just fine. Here is a way to ensure the data is clean:

```
df = df.assign(
    Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
).set_index('Date').sort_index()

# then, truncate anything before year 2020 in the plot:
ax = sns.scatterplot(
    x='Date', y='Col2', hue='Label',
    data=df.truncate(before='2020-01-01').groupby('Date').count())

# additionally, enforce a desired date format
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30)
```

Outcome (based on the example data):

[image]

**Original answer**:

Why not use `sns.barplot`?

```
sns.barplot(x='Date', y='Col2', hue='Label', data=df_plot)
```

But personally, in that case I would prefer just making a series, and using the builtin `pandas.plot`:

```
df.assign(
    Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
).groupby(['Date']).size().plot.bar()
```

or, if you want a scatterplot:

```
df.assign(
    Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
).groupby(['Date']).size().plot(style='o')
```

Comment: oh, ok, now I see your image. When I try with the sample data you provided, it works just fine for me. I thought you wanted a different image format. But now, my guess is that you have some spurious dates in your `df` (around year 2000).

Comment: The images was my previous one (with my attempt). I am getting the right plot with your code. The problem is that I have datetime on the x-axis (while in the dataframe I have correctly only date. I would need something like this 2020-05-28  format)

Comment: I updated the answer with some cleanup step (just in case) and some forceful formatting and rotation of the x-axis labels.